# Relación entre modelos laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo dos modelos llamados Recurso y Ejemplare, cada Recurso puede tener muchos ejemplares y cada ejemplar pertenece a un solo Recurso.

Esto tengo en el modelo Ejemplare

```
public function recurso()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Recurso::class);
    }
```

Esto tengo en el modelo Recurso

```
 public function ejemplares()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ejemplare::class);
    }
```

Puedo acceder a la información del ejemplar de la siguiente forma:

```
$recurso->ejemplare()->id
```

Pero ahora necesito saber cuantos ejemplares de ese recurso tienen su estado en disponible(1), no se como podría hacer el count además de la condición siguiendo esa nomenclatura.

Tengo esta función en el modelo ejemplar, que tiene como proposito contar los ejemplares disponibles.

```
public function estado_disponible($recurso)
    {
        $cantidad = Ejemplare::where('recurso_id', $recurso)->where('estado_ejemplare_id',1)->count()->first();
        return $cantidad;
    }
```

En la vista trato de recuperar la informacion

```
{{ $count = $recurso->ejemplares->estado_disponible($recurso->id) }}
```

Y recibo el siguiente error

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::estado_disponible does not exist

Migración de la tabla Ejemplar

```
Schema::create('ejemplares', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('recurso_id')->references('id')->on('recursos');
            $table->foreignId('estado_ejemplare_id')->references('id')->on('estado_ejemplares');
            $table->string('observaciones', 2000)->nullable();
            $table->date('fecha_adquisicion');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

PD: Soy nuevo con las relaciones y no se bien implementarlas, cualquier ayuda les agradeceré.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear un atributo en tu modelo recurso que regrese únicamente el número que buscas.

Por lo tanto, en tu modelo agregarías una función de la siguiente forma:

```
/**
 * Obtiene el número de ejemplares disponibles.
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getEjemplaresDisponiblesAttribute()
{
    return $this->ejemplares()->where('disponible', 1)->get()->count();
}
```

Dicho atributo puedes llamarlo de la siguiente manera:
`$recurso->ejemplaresDisponibles`

Alternativamente podrías usar `loadCount` y hacer lo siguiente:

En dónde sea que mandes a llamar tu recurso podrías hacerlo como.

```
$recurso->loadCount(['ejemplares' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('disponible', 1);
}]);
```

Y ya donde necesites el número de ejemplares puedes hacer
`$recurso->ejemplares_count`.

Comment: Gracias, por qué será que siempre me devuelve 0 ?

Comment: ¿Te da cero para cualquier recurso?

Comment: Si señor, me da cero en cualquier recurso

Comment: En la base de datos, ¿qué tipo de dato es disponible? Podrías poner la migración de la tabla `Ejemplar`?

Comment: Ya edite la publicación, dejar claro que el where lo actualice de acuerdo al nombre de mi campo es decir, cambie disponible por estado_ejemplare_id. El problema proviene de otro lugar.

Answer (score 3):

Aprovechando que ya definiste las relaciones de Eloquent podrías:

- Usar el método [`withCount`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) para el conteo de los modelos relacionados
- Ahora como solo interesa el conteo siempre que el estado sea igual a uno entonces a dicho método le pasamos un array asociativo, donde la clave es la nombre de la relación y el valor es una función donde construimos el *constraint* para filtrar
- Ahora agregamos el uso de [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) para evitar que en la colección sigan apareciendo resultados de aquellos conteos que no corresponden

La consulta:

```
Recurso::whereHas(['estadosEjemplares' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('estado', 1);    
}])->withCount(['estadosEjemplares' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('estado', 1);
}])->get();
```

**Edición**

Posterior a que agregaste la estructura de la migración de la tabla `ejemplares` te hago los siguientes comentarios:

- En los modelos: `Recurso` y `EstadoEjemplar` (**este último nombre lo estoy asumiendo ya que no esta disponible en la pregunta**) la relación que debes declarar es [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)  debido a que dicha tabla es intermedia y se alimenta en este caso de las pk de 2 tablas mas

Clase Recurso

```
class Recurso extends Model
{
    public function estadosEjemplares()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(EstadoEjemplar::class);
    }
}
```

Clase EstadoEjemplar

```
class EstadoEjemplar extends Model
{
    public function recursos()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(Recurso::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: El modelo EstadoEjemplar no tendría que llevar el método ejemplares? dado que con este es que tiene relación directa

Comment: Sugiero checar la doc. al respecto de como funcionan las relaciones *many to many* https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Estoy algo confundido, mira, un Recurso puede tener muchos ejemplares pero un Ejemplar solo puede tener un Estado, no se si many to many sea la mejor relación para este caso.

Comment: La cuestión **yo no estoy recomendando alguna relación de Eloquent, mi respuesta se basa en lo que expones en tu pregunta**, donde ejemplares almacena la pk tanto de recursos como de estado_ejemplares, si el vínculo entre las tablas es como me dices entonces el error viene desde la estructura de las tablas pues solo debería ser (**tabla recursos has many**) (**tabla ejemplares belongsTo**) y entonces en ejemplares tener alguna columna que almacene el estado mismo

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar basándome en la respuesta de Jacobo y en tus sugerencias, tomare en cuenta tus recomendaciones.